# Postfix Relay Based on Recepient

Tags: linux, email, postfix, relay, recipient

What is the best practice when one has to implement this sort of ruleset in postfix:

- Email sent to a@example.com, b@example.com, etc ought to be relayed to smtp.a.example.com.
- Email sent to everyone else @example.com ought to be relayed to smtp.b.example.com.

Ideally this shouldn't depend on the content of the message - just the RCPT TO SMTP command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `transport_maps` in your `main.cf`

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
#...
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
#...

#/etc/postfix/transport
a@example.com    smtp:smtp.a.example.com:25
b@example.com    smtp:smtp.a.example.com:25
example.com      smtp:smtp.b.example.com:25
```

---

```
transport_maps (default: empty)

Optional lookup tables with mappings from recipient address to (message delivery 
transport, next-hop destination). See transport(5) for details.

Specify zero or more "type:table" lookup tables. If you use this feature with 
local files, run "postmap /etc/postfix/transport" after making a change.
```

Ref: [Postfix Docs](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps)